# Where can one view the time of the day of one's entries and exit to/from the United States?

Tags: usa, international-travel, history, i-94

[Neither](https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/168429/1810) the I-94 nor the FOIA requesting the entries/exits contain the time of the day: they only contain the dates. Where can I find the time of the day of my entries and exits to/from the United States?

Comment: In your own diary? Be glad to be given the dates already.

Comment: Are you sure the time is even recorded? Your previous question including the FOI request response seems to indicate it may not be. Is it important to know the exact time? Is immigration status calculated in hours?

Comment: @Traveller not sure. Yes important

Comment: Genuine question: why? :-)

Comment: @Traveler from this user's other questions it is apparent that the accounting of arrival and departure is being made in connection with a naturalization application, so it's not about immigration status, which for a lawful permanent resident does not change on departure or arrival, but about physical presence.  The time is probably significant because the application excludes trips shorter than 24 hours but not those between 24 and 48 hours even if the return was on the calendar day following the departure.  Legally speaking, though, such trips would be irrelevant.

Comment: @phoog Thanks, interesting to know. Perhaps posing the OP’s question to https://help.cbp.gov/s/article/Article-ContactUs?language=en_US might be worth a try, if not done already of course :-)

Comment: If this level of detail is needed for the naturalization process, does that make this question one that belongs on Expats?

Comment: Hard to prove a negative, but if the FOIA response didn't include that data, then presumably either the government doesn't have it, or they are determined to withhold it.  Either way you won't be getting it.  And it doesn't seem likely that anyone other than the government would have it.  I'd suggest that you focus your efforts instead on how you can do without it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Regardless of whether or not such a website exists, relying on using their timestamps is a bad move. The general rule is that if time of the day matters, assume it’s the least favorable time for whatever immigration purposes you have. You don’t want to argue over time zones or hours worth of differences with a faceless bureaucrat who’s happy to reject your application or deny you entry.

See:

1. [Will it matter if I cross the Russian border 6 hours after my visa expires?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/27834/will-it-matter-if-i-cross-the-russian-border-6-hours-after-my-visa-expires)
2. [Is it possible to enter Russia by train 1-1.5 hours before the visa validity period starts?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/71950/is-it-possible-to-enter-russia-by-train-1-1-5-hours-before-the-visa-validity-per)
3. [Can I board if my flight arrives 1.5 hours before my UK visa becomes valid?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/94124/can-i-board-if-my-flight-arrives-1-5-hours-before-my-uk-visa-becomes-valid)